# How to make fields of pivot table updatable?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 9 I have table pivot table defined :

```
    Schema::create('article_vote', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        $table->foreignId('vote_id')->references('id')->on('votes')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        ...
    });
```

and having in both models methods with  belongsToMany
I can refer articles of a vote as :

```
$voteArticles = $vote->articles;
```

But when I try to update some data in article_vote table:

```
        $voteArticles = $vote->articles;
        \Log::info(varDump($voteArticles, ' -197 $voteArticles::'));

        $voteArticleUpdatedCount = 0;
        DB::beginTransaction();
        foreach ($voteArticles as $voteArticle) {
            try {
                $voteArticle->update($updateData); // I check these values in $updateData are diffrerent from data in  $voteArticle
                DB::Commit();
            } catch
            (\Exception $e) {
                DB::rollback();

                return sendErrorResponse($e->getMessage(), HTTP_RESPONSE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        }
```

In database trace I see

```
   BEGIN;  
  
   COMMIT;
```

statements but not any update statements. Looks like $voteArticle var can not be updated...

How to make it updatable ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-a-record-on-the-intermediate-table)?

Comment: `$vote->articles` doesn't return the `pivot` model, it instead returns articles related to a particular `vote_id`. I think you're looking for `$voteArticle->pivot->update(...)` But that only depends on how you defined those `belongsToMany` relationships and if you explicitly set up a `pivot` Model that extends `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot`.

Comment: [Laravel: Updating A Record On The Intermediate Table](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-a-record-on-the-intermediate-table)